# Anylogic PLE: I want a slider or other control to affect the arrival schedule for my source in anylogic

Tags: schedule, anylogic

I am doing my thesis using Anylogic and I've run into a little problem. I have two  different schedules for my source, in the process modeling section. I want/need a control option such as a slider to affect the used schedule in the source block. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance,

a student in need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there are many different ways and this is a quick way:

create a radio button control called `radio`as below:
[image]

Obviously, create 2 schedule objects, here named `schedule` and `schedule2`.

In your source, switch the schedule selection to a dynamic property where you can add code. Write as below:
[image]

Now the source applies the schedule you select in the radio button at any time.

cheers

Comment: btw, if the radio button doesn't work in the PLE, you can try the "Check box". In that case, the code in the source object would be "myCheckbox.isSelected() ? schedule : schedule2"

Comment: no worries. You asked a clear, concise question. That is typically rewarded around here :-) Keep it up and welcome to SOF :-)